# Compiler-Aided nullity contracts in c#?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

In Java it is possible to annotate methods with annotations that allow some processor to infer nullity and give you a warning/compiler error if you'd violate the nullity contract:

```
@NotNull    
public String returnSomething() {
    return null; // would give a warning as you violate the contract.
}

// at call site
if (returnSomething() != null) { // would give you a warning about unneccessary if
}

public int doSomethingElse(@NotNull String arg1, @Nullable String arg2) {
    return arg1.length() + arg2.length(); // would give you a warning about potential NPE when accessing arg2 without a check
}

// at call site
doSomethingElse(null, null); // would give you a warning about violating contract for arg1
```

Is there something similar available for C#?

Comment: Have you looked into [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Hi Yuriy, I have, though I was hoping for a less verbose approach. Also I see no really neat way with Conde Contracts to specify that a return value can be potentially null.

Comment: @JanThomä That's because that's the default. If you don't specify any promises for the result, then code must assume the method may return `null`.

Comment: @hvd shouldn't the compiler issue a warning then,  when I try to use a potentially null return value without a previous if check?

Comment: @JanThomä It does, assuming Code Contracts is installed, static checking is enabled, and the warning level is suitably high.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use **Fody's** [NullGuard](https://github.com/Fody/NullGuard). It works at compile time (generates appropriate IL code):

```
public class Sample
{
    public void SomeMethod(string arg)
    {
        // throws ArgumentNullException if arg is null.
    }

    public void AnotherMethod([AllowNull] string arg)
    {
        // arg may be null here
    }

    [return: AllowNull]
    public string MethodAllowsNullReturnValue()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When it gets compiled:

```
public class SampleOutput
{
    public void SomeMethod(string arg)
    {
        if (arg == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("arg");
        }
    }

    public void AnotherMethod(string arg)
    {
    }

    public string MethodAllowsNullReturnValue()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

2) If you use ReSharper, you can use [Contract Annotations](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/08/15/contract-annotations-in-resharper-7/).